# Resolved alert when alarm is cleared in slack notification in Elastic Watchers

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, elastic-stack, slack

I have seen many applications sending {Firing}Alarm as well {Resolved}Alarm in Slack notification. I am in the process of writing alerting based on Elastic Watchers but unable to find out right direction. Sending alarm is pretty straight forward but how to send the RESOLVED notification for the same DOWN alarm?
Any guidance or documentation is appreciated